# Css conflict with android web view

Tags: android, css, webview

A part of a webpage i am displaying on android webview is not being showed, after checking i discovered the problem is a css class which is the following:

```
.problemClass a li {

color: #163758;

text-decoration: none;

}

.problemClass a:hover  li{



    color:#Fff;

    text-decoration: none;

}


.problemClass{

padding:0;

display: block;

list-style: none;

width: 100%;

height:207px;

float: left;

position: relative;

margin: 5px 0 25px 0;

font-size: 20px;

color: #163758;

background-image: url(../images/sombraLista.png);

background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-position:center bottom;

font-size: 45px;

font-weight: bold;

line-height:45px;   

}

.problemClass li {

padding:20px;

height: 50px;

background-image: url(../images/bkInfonon.png);

background-repeat: repeat-x;

}


.problemClass li:nth-child(odd) { 

background-image: url(../images/bkInfopar.png);

background-repeat: repeat-x; }

The html structure in that part is 

<div class="problemClass">

      <ul>
         <a href="">
             <li></li>
           </a>
       </ul>

</div>
```

Does anybody know what may be causing this conflict?

Thanks